# Does the amount of data affect the recognition speed?[tensorflow]

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Hello, I have a tensorflow model, I coached it in about 300 pictures, the training took place in the Google cloud, I recognize it there and send a response to my server. The question is, does the amount of data affect the recognition speed, that is, will it be recognized faster if I train 3,000 pictures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your recognition speed is dependant only on your computation graph.

The accuracy of recognition is dependent on the training images used.

Comment: thank you for the answer, it's strange that the cloud is recognized 3 times longer than local, having the same model

Comment: Regarding the performance, you could check this Cloud [TPUs](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/) to improve performance